# TFVC Share feature?

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc

I currently use SourceGear Vault for version control but I'm looking at switching over to TFS.  Vault has a nice feature called "Share", which effectively lets you put the same file in different points in the tree - check it out in one place and it is locked in the other, check it back in and both copies change.  I've had a brief look at TFVC and I can't see anything like this - am I missing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for "Share" in TFS.  You may be able to leverage two different TFS workspaces to accommodate your requirements, or you may be required to do some restructuring of your code.

(Historical note:  "Sharing" actually came from Visual SourceSafe and SourceGear Vault added it because we wanted feature parity with Visual SourceSafe.  Our goal at that time was to build "a compelling replacement to Visual SourceSafe", which meant we had to implement share and - much worse - pin.)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any plan to implement Share in TFS or to integrate with Vault?

Comment: Sorry, there is not.  There may be a different way of providing the same functionality, though, within the existing system.